# Which version of "find an occurence" function is faster?

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm

I'm not very strong in algorithms. There are two versions of function, which returns if there any capital letter in passed string is.
First doesn't check the condition on each iteration. Second finishes after first occurence of capital letter.
Which is faster **in general**?

```
bool isAnyCapLetters(const std::string &s) {
    int flag = 0;
    for (auto el : s)
        flag += isupper(el);
    return static_cast<bool>(flag);
}
bool isAnyCapLetters(const std::string &s) {
    for (auto el : s)
        if (isupper(el)) return true;
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: Both appear to be O(n), so time is likely equal

Comment: @staticx Worst-case asymptotic complexity isn't the only useful measure of performance.

Comment: @delnan: True, in this case though it is iterating over an unknown string of unknown length. I would think you would have to consider the worst-case. Plus, the functions are not equal because one would return immediately if it found it sooner because one is a counting function, other is just a validity check.

Comment: `if` spend less than `+=`, and may break the loop early

Comment: @Tim: "`if` spend less than `+=`" - unless branch prediction fails, in which case it could be much slower. Measurement is the only way to be sure.

Comment: @staticx I didn't say you shouldn't consider the worst case, I said you shouldn't *only* consider it. @Tim "`if` spend less than `+=`" is an atrociously bad cost model, not only because of branch prediction.

Comment: with a quantum computer both would be equally fast...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second one returns early and will be faster for a long string starting with a capital letter.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a string like `This_is_a_useless_but_not_so_very_short_string_whooptifriggindoo`, then the first function will loop through all the chars and will have to do a cast at the end. The second function will see that the first char is in uppercase and will immediately return without any cast. Thus the second function will be faster.